# How to save newly created commands in the terminal

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

is there anyway to save newly created commands in the terminal?
Every time, I exit the terminal, all of the commands I created are lost.

Thank you.

Comment: you could get them by running `history` command.

Comment: add them to .bashrc as functions.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the <kbd>↑</kbd> key
2. Use the reverse search integrated in the terminal by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>r</kbd>
3. Use a bin file

   - open gedit by typing gedit in the dash
   - enter `#/bin/bash` in the first row
   - now enter each command in a new line
   - save it in `/home/[username]/bin/` without an ending (gedit does it automatically right)
   - go into nautilus (the data explorer) and right click the file
   - go on properties and check the box "allow executing file" under properties
   - now just click doubled
   - a window saying <kbd>run in terminal</kbd>,<kbd>display</kbd>,<kbd>cancel</kbd>,<kbd>run</kbd>
   - just click <kbd>run in terminal</kbd> or run
   - now you're script must run...

an example for the file:

```
#/bin/bash
gnome-system-settings
```

---

The first one is easier to use with one command, but the second one is better for running multiple ones after each other.